# neo4j shortest with connector node and multiple options

Tags: neo4j, cypher, dijkstra

I have Cities, Roads and Transporters in my database.
A Road is connected with a From and To relationship to two (different) Cities. Each road has also a property distance (in kilometers).
Multiple Transporters could have a relationship to Roads. Every Transporter has a price (per kilometer).

Now my question. I want the cheapest option to get a packet from city A to B. There could be a direct road or else we have to go via other cities and transporters. And I want explicitly use the Dijkstra algorithm for this.

Can this query be done in Cypher? And if not, how can it be done using the Neo4J Java API?

Comment: you can use shortestPath with Cypher or Dijkstra via the neo4j rest api

Comment: For as far as I know with shortestPath you can take a property as cost. But how to take the distance of road and multiply it with price of a transporter?
And when there are multiple transporters for a specific Road?

Comment: I would advise that you come first with a model, and maybe a test dataset in http://console.neo4j.org . For now except telling you that it is possible and point you to documentation, we can not help you that much

Comment: Do you mean something like this for a dataset: [link]http://console.neo4j.org/r/c9kidj[/link]?

Comment: Exactly ! so now we can play :)

Comment: Ok, do you want a model? On this dataset, I want to know (for example) what are the cheapest options to get a packet from CityA to CityD. The documentation on the neo4j website is not very detailed (in my opinion) about shortestPath or Graph Algorithms. The examples are always in the form of a relationship which has a cost.

Comment: Well this is the goal of calculating the cheapest way : a cost. Now concerning your dataset, if you do (a)-[]->(b) with a directed path, there is no paths possible

Answer (score 1):

Based on your [sample dataset](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=c9kidj), I think there is a modelisation problem that makes maybe things difficult, certainly for matching on directed relationships.

However this is already how you can find the lowest cost path :

```
MATCH (a:City { name:'CityA' }),(d:City { name:'CityD' })
MATCH p=(a)-[*]-(d)
WITH p, filter(x IN nodes(p) 
               WHERE 'Road' IN labels(x)) AS roads
WITH p, reduce(dist = 0, x IN roads | dist + x.distance) AS totalDistance
RETURN p, totalDistance
ORDER BY totalDistance
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: But for a real-world use-case I'd probably implement it in the java-api using the Dijkstra or A* algorithm and provide the neccessary cost functions and relationship-expanders (that skip over the "Road" node.)